# Is there a way to alias column groups?

Tags: mysql, sql

What i'm trying to do is join multiple tables together which have the same column names. However I don't want to specify the columns individually in the Select output.

The below obviously won't work but is there a way to achieve something along the following lines?

example

```
select a.* as A, b.* as B, c.* as C
from tableA
join tableB ON ...
join tableC ON ...
```

with the intended output columns to look something like this -->
A_name | A_id | B_name | B_id | C_name | C_id

Comment: The answer is: No.

Comment: No, you will have to specify the names. multiple tables all with the same columns sounds like a design problem.

Comment: It's rarely appropriate to use `SELECT *` in the first place. You should just list the columns that you need.

Comment: Its not possible that you want.

Comment: Fair enough. Figured I'd check before ruling it out.